# How can I have a view controller open only on the first launch

Tags: java, ios, macos, viewcontroller

I have built a simple app with Xcode 5, using very basic functions. As my app is going to have a large target audience, I want it to support different languages. I have done the translation part, but what I want is a view controller which displays language selection only the first time the app is opened. I am new to developing apps, so please explain me in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The app will automatically use the strings file for the current locale. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: what's up with the java tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults to store data between app launches. You will need something like:

```
static NSString * const kShowIntroductionKey = @"ShowIntroductionKey";

- (void)showOnFirstLaunch
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL wasIntroductionShowed = [userDefaults boolForKey:kShowIntroductionKey];

    if (!wasIntroductionShowed){

        // Show your screen here!

        [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:kShowIntroductionKey];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

Also may be it will be better to use native iOS localization mechanism.